# Different results every time I run the same scrapy project

Tags: scrapy

I am very new to Scrapy. I managed to create a Scrapy project, run it to crawl a website and save the information scrapped in a csv file. However, every time I run it, it seems the number and order of the web pages being crawled are different. I am pretty sure the web site is static during these period of time. Just in general, is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

From scrapy [architecture overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html):

> Scrapy is written with Twisted, a popular event-driven networking
>   framework for Python. Thus, it’s implemented using a non-blocking (aka
>   asynchronous) code for concurrency.

Hence you should expect the order to be different. As an example if you have now on [stack](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=dfo) of scheduler two pending Requests R1 and R2 with R1 on the top. R1 will be processed first by scheduler. But since R2 can be processed almost at the same time, it can be piped out faster, than R1. If you want the order to be the same set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` or `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` to one. To check why you have different number of items in the output you can pipe out the `response.url`.